# CSS grid align-content on parent overrides align-self of child

Tags: css, css-grid

Hi I am trying to create 2 column grid. Each column will have a title, image text and a button.
The text length can vary hence I want to push down the button to the bottom so that all the buttons in the columns align.

When I use `align-self: end` on the button is works.
But there is some misalignment with the other elements. So I used `align-content: start` on the parent but then the button alignment is not working anymore.

[Here is a jsbin with the example.](https://jsbin.com/galikoduye/edit?css,output)

Comment: Pardon me, but why are you using grid here? Looks like you have to similar 'boxes' side by side. I'd just drop the grid, make each 'box' without grid, and maybe use flex to align them side by side.

Comment: @Celsiuss i used it cause i will have more columns. But i got it to work with `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, min-content)`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, min-content)`

[Here is the working example.](https://jsbin.com/neroqil/1/edit?css,output)